# Entity Framework 6 Many-to-many wants to insert duplicate rows

Tags: sql, entity-framework

It shouldn't be this hard! I am about to give up on EF...

My model has weekly newspaper Editions. Each Edition can have many Classifieds. Each Classified can appear in one or more Editions. My models:

```
public class Classifieds
{ 
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ClassifiedId { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<EditionModel> Editions { get; set; }
}

public class EditionModel
{
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int EditionId { get; set; } // This is YYYYWW, WW = week number
  public Date PublicationDate { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Classifieds> Classifieds { get; set; }
}
```

The OnModelCreating override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<EditionModel>()
     .Property(z => z.EditionId)
     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

   modelBuilder.Entity<EditionModel>()
     .HasMany(c => c.Classifieds)
     .WithMany(d => d.Editions)
     .Map(x =>
     {
       x.MapLeftKey("EditionId");
       x.MapRightKey("ClassifiedId");
       x.ToTable("EditionModelClassifieds");
     });
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The Create Classifieds Action code (HTTP put):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Classifieds classifieds, int[] EditionList)
{
  var allPubs = PopulateEditionList(); // Current and next 12 editions
  db.Set<Classifieds>().Attach(classifieds);
  db.Entry(classifieds).Collection(x => x.Editions).Load();
  foreach (var p in EditionList)
  {
      var anEd = (from x in allPubs where x.EditionId == p select x).Single();
      classifieds.Editions.Add(anEd);
  }
  ...
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var ads = db.Classifieds.Add(classifieds);
     await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     return View("Receipt", classifieds);
  }
  ...
}
```

On submit of a new Classifieds, I get

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.EditionModels'.  
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EditionModels'.
```

Why does EF insist on wanting insert duplicate rows in EditionModels instead of just linking the junction table row to an existing row therein? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that EditionModel was not part of the context. Thank you, Slauma for pointing me in the right direction. The corrected Create Action is:

```
...
classifieds.Editions = new List<EditionModel>();
foreach (var p in EditionList)
{
   var ed = await db.EditionModel.FindAsync(p);
   if (ed == null)
      ed = new EditionModel { EditionId = p, PublicationDate = (from q in allPubs where                       q.EditionId == p select q).Single().PublicationDate };
   InsertOrUpdate<EditionModel>(ed);
   classifieds.Editions.Add(ed);
}
...
```

The rest of the code is as above.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `PopulateEditionList()` doesn't attach the editions to the context. Add this line in the `foreach` loop:

```cs
db.Set<EditionModel>().Attach(anEd);
```

Possibly you can simplify the whole procedure. I'm not sure why you load the editions into memory. You could just create a "stub entity" based on the key which is enough to create the relationship. Also attaching `classifieds` to the context seems redundant because you want to add it as a new entity to the database. Trying to load related editions from the database for a parent entity that doesn't exist yet in the DB seems redundant as well. The result can only be an empty collection.

So, the following simpler version might work as well:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Classifieds classifieds, int[] EditionList)
{
    classifieds.Editions = new List<EditionModel>();
    foreach (var p in EditionList)
    {
        var anEd = new EditionModel { EditionId = p };
        db.Set<EditionModel>().Attach(anEd);
        classifieds.Editions.Add(anEd);
    }
    //...
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var ads = db.Classifieds.Add(classifieds);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return View("Receipt", classifieds);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, Slauma. The solution you proposed did not work, MSSQL tried to add a duplicate row into the EditionModels table. This was my original problem... Here is the output: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.EditionModelClassifieds_dbo.EditionId". The conflict occurred in database "ipdb", table "dbo.EditionModels", column 'EditionId'.
The statement has been terminated.